# How to make html pages editable on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am working with play 2.1.0 and using jquery to design a html pages. I am looking for functionality where when user first time signs in to my website, the UI should be in readonly mode. When user clicks on "Edit" button certain fields across the web pages will become editable at a time. After edits are done, user can save changes and web pages will become readonly again.

I searched for some jquery plugins, but all the plug-ins work in a different way. They make a particular html element editable on jquery events. like a text box will become editable if user click/doubleclick on that particular textbox only. Something like jeditable plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Is there any plugin available as per my requirement? or there is any other way to implement the required functionality?

**Edit**

I solved this problem by having separate file for edit and view. I maintain a variable in session, and based on its value I render a edit or view page.

Comment: Can you not just search all your inputs and make them editable like `$('input, select, textarea').removeAttr('disabled')` or something like that?

Comment: I can not keep all my elements disabled by default, because in read mode all the elements like input box, select option, teaxt area should look like a plain taxt like if its a label.

Comment: What you are asking for is complete business requirement to be fullfilled by a plugin. Very unlikely there will be one. You can use the plugins u mentioned and build on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#EditButton').click(function(){
 $('.input').show();
  $('.label').hide();
 });

 </script>

 <li class="label"> <label>example</label></li>
 <li class="input"> <input type="text" value="example" /></li>
```